# Should questions about the first use of a notation be on topic?

Tags: discussion, scope

There's been some disagreement on the topicality of "[Where do Feynman Diagrams Appear for the first time?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/361253/where-do-feynman-diagrams-appear-for-the-first-time)", so I wanted to bring the issue to meta to get input from the community. It could be considered a historical question, which speaks to it being off topic, but it's also asking for the work which introduced a specific notation, which is (at least quite close to) what the [specific-reference](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/specific-reference) was created for, and I would say that speaks to it being on topic. What does the community think about this question and others like it which ask for the first work to use a certain kind of notation? Should such questions be on topic?

To guide the discussion, here are three possible outcomes I anticipate (but other options are certainly welcome):

- We could decide that questions of the form "What was the first paper/book/etc. to use [notation]?" are, in general, on topic (and should be tagged [specific-reference](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/specific-reference)).
- We could decide that questions of the form "What was the first paper/book/etc. to use [notation]?" are *off topic*, but questions of the form "What paper announced the discovery of [phenomenon]?" remain on topic (and should be tagged [specific-reference](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/specific-reference)).
- Diverging somewhat from the main question, we could decide to make all questions of the form "What was the first paper/book/etc. to [do X]?" for *any* X off topic. That would be a change in the scope of the site - basically we'd be rendering the primary use of [specific-reference](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/specific-reference) obsolete.

Comment: Changing 'phenomenon' for 'tool' in your second bullet point, it sounds like in that specific case the decision hinges on whether Feynman diagrams are notation vs tools. I would strongly lean towards the latter.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I believe it should be on-topic.

It's a fine line, but I think the request for a paper which first uses a certain notation is pretty much *exactly* what the [specific-reference](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/specific-reference) tag was for, so I think it'd be kind of inconsistent to make it off-topic but a specific discovery on-topic.

Completely removing [specific-reference](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/specific-reference) as an on-topic subject also doesn't make much sense to me. A final note - this sort of question might be one on topic on both History of Science/Mathematics *and* here, which isn't necessarily a bad thing.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "it"? Questions asking for the first introduction of a given concept / tool / formalism / phenomenon, or questions asking about the first use of a given notation? You can have a perfectly functional specific-reference tag for the former while still sending the later to HSM.

Comment: @EmilioPisanty I'd say both =)

Comment: +1, especially for "this sort of question might be one on topic on both History of Science/Mathematics *and* here, which isn't necessarily a bad thing."

Answer (score 1):

I concur with @heather's answer that it should be on topic.

Moreover, I think that whenever we have a meta question along the lines of:

> Should this incredibly specific, very low volume class of questions be on topic?

The answer should be `yes, they are on topic`. I'm not really sure what purpose any other answer could serve.